# use entity-framework to map int column to enum property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4.1

I have a enum type called `Operation` like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum Operation
{
    None = 0,
    View = (1 << 0),
    Add = (1 << 1),
    Edit = (1 << 2),
    Delete = (1 << 3),
    ReservedA = (1 << 4),
    ReservedB = (1 << 5),
    Admin = (View | Add | Edit | Delete)
}
```

and table `permission` contains a `operations` column. This table maps to a class like this:

```
[Table("rolepermission")]
public class Permission : IComparable
{
    private int _id = 0;

    private Operation _operations = Operation.None;

    private List<UserRole> _roles = null;

    public Permission()
    {
        _roles = new List<UserRole>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(Operation))]
    public Operation Operations
    {
        get { return _operations; }
        set { _operations = value; }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there any elegant way that can map it?

I think creating an `int`-type property is not the best way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way in .NET 4.0 is to use int property persisted to database and non-mapped enum property which will convert the int internally (or during entity loading and entity persistence). Alternatively you can try a [wrapper approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/05/tip-23-how-to-fake-enums-in-ef-4.aspx).

.NET 4.5 supports enums directly <strike>but I don't think Flags are supported</strike> (Edit: Check Kamyar's comment).

Comment: Based on nathan's comment at http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/video-entity-framework-5-enums-and-moving-solution-from-ef-4-3/ and the article at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/06/29/enumeration-support-in-entity-framework.aspx, it seems like EF 5 handles flags storage but `HasFlag` extension method is not yet supported.

Comment: @Kamyar `HasFlag` is now supported in EF 6.1